# Problems with making POST request

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

Using one site I became bored with clicking every time I want to change some data, so I want to send this data automatically. I found that data which is send is next:
[image]

But I don't know how to send data correctly. I'm using ajax and it looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:(some url),
    type: 'POST',
    data: ({
        is_ajax:'true',
        module:'check_yourself',
        action:'check',
        nums[2]['board'][1]:'false',
        nums[2]['board'][2]:'false',
        nums[2]['board'][3]:'false'
    }),
    success:function(data){
        alert()
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work, so what the matter is?

Comment: because `nums[2]['board'][1]` should be `"nums[2][board][1]"`. You should see console errors related to your assignment of an object key.

Comment: @A.Lau and what about is_ajax, and values of each variable? Should it also be with ''

Comment: If you're unsure, you should always wrap your keys with `"` before and after. `is_ajax` is fine because it doesn't carry special symbols, i.e. `[` and `]` in your case.

Comment: @A.Lau and all values(false, check) should also be wrapped?

Comment: stuff that's already recognised by the system, i.e. variables/numbers do not need to be wrapped.

Comment: @A.Lau I missed it, but there is one more variable to send: 'type' and it's empty, so what I have to send using ajax?

Comment: empty `""` just send nothing.